# SQL count aggregate functions and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Im just learning SQL specially on aggregate functions and subquery

I have a database table with columns `c0, c1, c2, c3`.

My query:

```
SELECT ID, count(ID) 
FROM ((select ID from tbl1 where c0 BETWEEN 4 and 7) 
UNION ALL
(select ID from tbl1 where c1 BETWEEN 5 and 7) 
UNION ALL
(select ID from tbl1 where c2 BETWEEN 6 and 10) 
UNION ALL
(select ID from tbl1 where c3 BETWEEN 1 and 5)) AS tbl
GROUP BY ID HAVING count(ID) >= 2
```

Can the query above rewritten such that result will be faster? Or how to make my query faster?

Comment: Do you really have 4 different columns that you are testing?  What happens when a row meets more than one condition (or is that the purpose of the query)?

Comment: thats the purpose, to count the appearances..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need aggregation at all.  Just count the matches in each row.

Assuming that `id` is unique in the table:

```
select id,
       ((c0 between 4 and 7) + (c1 between 5 and 7) + (c2 between 6 and 10) +
        (c3 between 1 and 5)
       ) as cnt
from tbl1
having cnt >= 2;
```

MySQL treats booleans in a numeric context as numbers, with 1 for true and 0 for false, so the expression `c0 between 4 and 7` is basically equivalent to `case when c0 between 4 and 7 then 1 else 0 end`, but easier to write.

MySQL also extends the `having` clause so it can work without a `group by`.  In this case, it behaves like a `where`, but you can use aliases defined in the `select`.

Note:  this is slightly more complicated if the columns have `NULL` values.

If `id` is not unique, then you can basically do the same thing with aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum((c0 between 4 and 7) + (c1 between 5 and 7) + (c2 between 6 and 10) +
           (c3 between 1 and 5)
          ) as cnt
from tbl1
group by id
having cnt >= 2;
```

However, a column called `id` should be unique.

Comment: @mich . . . You cannot use an index in the query.  In order to use indexes, you would need to take the approach in your original query.  However, I suspect that a full table scan would be faster than merging the results from four indexes, unless each of the conditions is very, very restrictive (say less than 1% of the rows).